# Javascript fetch's text() or json() never resolve and just hangs forever

Tags: javascript, next.js, fetch-api

I am trying to do a fetch in a new nextjs 13 project (I'm not sure if this is a js or nextjs issue) and use console.logs to watch the code execution.

```
let url = `${BASE}/${module}/${path}`;
      url += "?" + new URLSearchParams(params).toString();
      console.log(`${url}`);
      let response = await fetch(`${url}`, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "expect-cache-tag": API_KEY,
          Authorization:
            "Bearer ...",
        },
      });


      console.log(4);
      const text = await response.text();
      console.log(5);
      try {
        console.log(6);
        const json = JSON.parse(text);
        console.log(7);
        return json;
      } catch (err) {
        throw new Error("Did not receive JSON, instead received: " + text);
      }
    } catch (err: any) {
      console.log(8);
      let response = err.response;
      return response;
    }
```

With some requests it runs through just fine, but with others I can see it gets stuck with the logs:

```
1
2
https://...
4
```

So it seems it gets stuck resolving the text(), and it does the same if I use json().
Here is the response and can see it returns a 200:

```
Response {
  size: 0,
  timeout: 0,
  [Symbol(Body internals)]: {
    body: PassThrough {
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 5,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kCallback)]: null
    },
    disturbed: false,
    error: null
  },
  [Symbol(Response internals)]: {
    url: 'https://...',
    status: 200,
    statusText: 'OK',
    headers: Headers { [Symbol(map)]: [Object: null prototype] },
    counter: undefined
  }
}
```

Thank you for any insights

Comment: yep, i think you got problem same as mine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74360096/next-js-fetch-in-middleware-hangs-forever-while-wait-res-json?noredirect=1#comment131274819_74360096

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems it was a known issues and talked about in the next.js GitHub: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/41853

Answer (score 1):

in my case, it only happened when i tried to fetch api from local in middleware, then i try wrap api use route api https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction and it works, don't know why

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).